# List of lists from file

Tags: parsing, hash-map, applescript

I'm writing a sub-routine in AppleScript to get text from a file and insert that text in a list of lists forming a dictionary.

Text File:

```
a:b
c:d
e:f
```

Expected list:

```
{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}}
```

Here's my code:

```
on getDictionary(filePath)
    set dictionary to {}
    set dictionaryFile to paragraphs of (read POSIX file filePath)
    repeat with entry in dictionaryFile
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {":"}
        set delimitedEntry to every text item of entry
        copy delimitedEntry to the end of dictionary
    end repeat
    return dictionary
end getDictionary
```

I'm wondering if this is a good approach for my goal. It does produce the desired result.